# Adding tables in spot fire without doing it manually

Tags: mysql, ironpython, spotfire

I am using Smartsheet as a data source for Spotfire tool.

In Smartsheet, we are having lots of tables.

By using that table some analysis made in Spotfire... Smartsheet will update new tables daily instead of adding each table into Spotfire manually.

Is there any way to automate it?